# Is it possible to forbid UIDatePicker auto change language?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to forbid UIDatePicker auto change language?
I prefer that English speakers can read information in English even they are in different country.
It looks like UIDatePicker auto change its language base on regions.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the [`.locale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006806-CH3-SW8) property of the date picker.

(BTW I don't believe the iPhone OS will change language base on which country you are in. The user should have changed the language manually to cause the locale to change.)

Comment: But .locale is deprecated in iOS5... How can I achieve it now?

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone or iPod Touch will only change the language used in your UI components if the user changes the Internationalization settings in the Settings app.  In other words, don't worry about it.

If every iOS device changed languages every time the user took their device to another country, you would have a lot of confused people!!!